# <If> clause failing with RewriteRule

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I already have the following directive in my `.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,C]

    <If "-f %{DOCUMENT_ROOT} . '/maintenance/off.php'">
    RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=1.2.3.4
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/maintenance
    RewriteRule .* /maintenance/off.php [L]
    </If>

</IfModule>
```

This is not working properly. The `If` clause is triggering, but when I access it from the allowed IP it fails somehow. If I just remove the `<If>` clause it works again. I could not find how to use `RewriteCond` to check if my file flag exists.

EDIT: I'm using `RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/maintenance/off.html -f` and it is working fine, I'm just find it odd that the `<If>` isn't working.

Comment: Can't you replace the `<If>` by some `RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/maintenance/off.php -f` or alike?

Comment: Yep, in the end I'm using that and it works. I'm just baffled why the `<If>` keeps failing... :/